# Remove dash between strings and Capitalize the String in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I am trying to capitalize the String after removing all dashes in between.

so this `i-am-string` would become `I am string`.

This is what I tried, but it does capitalize, but I don't know how to remove dashes and capitalize.

```
function tweakFunction (string) {

     return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: This is not JavaScript. Post your JS code.

Comment: Ok, that looks better, check my answer see if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a couple regex, like in the PHP version you previously posted:

```
var result = str
  .replace(/-/g, ' ')
  .replace(/^./, function(x){return x.toUpperCase()})
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function tweakFunction(str) {
   str = str.replace(/-/g, ' ');
   return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1);
}
console.log(tweakFunction('i-am-string')); //=> "I am string"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Capitalize the first letter of the string and the rest of it to be Lowercase */
function capitalize(word){
    return word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.substring(1).toLowerCase()
}
console.log(capitalize("john")); //John
console.log(capitalize("BRAVO")); //Bravo
console.log(capitalize("BLAne")); //Blane
```

Comment: They also want to remove all dashes.

Answer (score 0):

```
//split into array of multiple words using the dash, iterate through each word to make whatever change you want, then join.

const formatSlug = (string) => {
  return string
    .split('-')
    .map((str) => str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1))
    .join(' ');
};
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code rather than posting only code.